# Почему теряется контекст в JS?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите почему теряется контекст для method.say, почему он указывает на window вместо user, ведь в call указано что this ссылается на user?

```
var f = function(whatever) {  

    console.log(this);  
    console.log(this.name);  
    console.log(this.lastName);  

    whatever();
}

var user = {  
    "name": "John",  
    "lastName": "Snow"   
}

var method = {  
    "say": function() {  
        console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.lastName);  
    }  
}  

f.call(user, method.say);
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` для `f`, но не для `whatever`.

```
var f = function(whatever) {  

    console.log(this);  
    console.log(this.name);  
    console.log(this.lastName);  

    whatever();
}

var user = {  
    "name": "John",  
    "lastName": "Snow"   
}

var method = {  
    "say": function() {  
        console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.lastName);  
    }  
}  

f.call(user, method.say.bind(user));
```

```
var f = function(whatever) {  

    console.log(this);  
    console.log(this.name);  
    console.log(this.lastName);  

    whatever.call(this);
}

var user = {  
    "name": "John",  
    "lastName": "Snow"   
}

var method = {  
    "say": function() {  
        console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.lastName);  
    }  
}  

f.call(user, method.say);
```

Comment: Разве call не ссылает  все this в функции на указанный контекст? Я думал это и на аргументы передаваемые функции с помощью call распространяется.

Comment: @Дмитрий, нет, не так.